# How to load initial realm in keycloak server with docker?

Tags: docker, keycloak

I'm starting a `keycloak` server and want to let the server import a default realm (as for the start). But even this does not work:

`/tmp/example-realm.json`:

```
{
  "realm": "springboot-quickstart",
  "enabled": true,
  "sslRequired": "external",
  "registrationAllowed": true,
  "requiredCredentials": [ "password" ],
  "clients": [
    {
      "clientId": "service-springboot",
      "enabled": true,
      "bearerOnly": true,
      "protocol": "openid-connect"
    }
  ]
}
```

Start with:

```
docker run -p 8180:8080
  -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
  -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
  -e KEYCLOAK_IMPORT=/tmp/example-realm.json
  -v /tmp/example-realm.json:/tmp/example-realm.json
  quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:17.0.0 start-dev
```

Result: only the `master` realm exists, but my imported realm is missing.

Instead, when I go to the admin page of keycloak and import that file manually, the *client* "springboot-quickstart" is imported into my `master` realm successfully. So the json file should be fine in general.

So why doesn't this work on initial startup?

Comment: This is weird. It has the same environment variables as we use (although our keycloak image is jboss/keycloak) Are there any error or warn logs?

Comment: There are no error or failure logs. I not using anything special here, just the default docker image as written above, with the exact json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in 17.0.0 it seems like, but will be fixed in 17.0.1.

See [this issue](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/10216)

Comment: This is accepted as the answer but 17.0.1 is out and this doesn't seem to work as OP stated. Can you describe in what this is fixed or how to do it in 17.0.1? The linked issue also does not give a resolution to this question unless you are referring to the other issue they link to from there which states it will be fixed in 18.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

I could fix it as follows:
`-e JAVA_OPTS="-Dkeycloak.import=/tmp/example-realm.json"`

But still I'd like to know why `-e KEYCLOAK_IMPORT` does not work.

Answer (score 1):

A docker-compose approach with newer keycloak releases works for me. `./apps/keycloak/import` directory contains my `realm-export.json`.

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:22.0.0
    ports:
      - 8062:8080
    volumes:
      - ./apps/keycloak/import:/opt/keycloak/data/import
    command: start-dev --import-realm
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
      - DB_VENDOR=postgres
      - DB_ADDR=database
      - DB_DATABASE=keycloak
      - DB_USER=postgres
      - DB_PASSWORD=postgres
```

Answer (score 0):

Using keycloak 18.0.1 with the `--import-realm` flag I was able to drop my json into the data/import folder and it seems to work:

```
docker run -p 8180:8080
  -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
  -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
  -v /tmp/example-realm.json:/opt/keycloak/data/import/example-realm.json
  quay.io/keycloak/keycloak start-dev --import-realm
```